# nil __weak self - Why it's happend?

Tags: ios, objective-c, block, null, weak

I want to use weak self in blocks, but in block this weakSelf become nil

Just created, before block (try to use different variants) - looks like all ok

[image]

But later in block - each variant nil

[image]

Whats done wrong? Can anyone explain?

**EDIT**

```
SPHVideoPlayer *videoPlayer = [[SPHVideoPlayer alloc] initVideoPlayerWithURL:urlToFile];
[videoPlayer prepareToPlay];
```

Initialization

```
#pragma mark - LifeCycle

- (instancetype)initVideoPlayerWithURL:(NSURL *)urlAsset
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        [self initialSetupWithURL:urlAsset];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)initialSetupWithURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    NSDictionary *assetOptions = @{ AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey : @YES };
    self.urlAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:assetOptions];
}
```

And also method that use block

```
- (void)prepareToPlay
{
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    __weak SPHVideoPlayer *weakSealf2 = self;
    NSArray *keys = @[@"tracks"];
    [self.urlAsset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:keys completionHandler:^{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [weakSelf startLoading];
        });
    }];
}
```

Comment: Well you the instance that called the block has been deallocated before the block was called. Either you are not keep a strong reference to the `SPHVIdeoPlayer` instance or you are having some multi threading issue.

Comment: @rckoenes - looks like you are right - my instance has been deallocated before the block was called... But i try to follow as its recommended - call weakself for not getting retain cycle, but in this case think I miss something

Comment: @Rob I create instance of `SPHVideoPlayer` and after custom `init` method try to call this method on created object within this block inside - please see EDIT

Comment: @Kirill Yep, but as you deduced, this `SPHVideoPlayer` is falling out of scope and is getting released. Assuming you don't want it to be released, you just have to choose a scope that keeps it around (e.g. making it a property of the view controller that is showing the video).

Comment: @Rob so you mean that `Always use weakSelf in block` not really true, and it depends.

Comment: @Rob, I understand, and many thank for explanation If you want - make answer I'll mark it as Accept one

Comment: The alternative to weakSelf being nil is a crash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As rckoenes suggested, this `SPHVideoPlayer` is falling out of scope and is getting released. Assuming you don't want it to be released, you just have to choose a scope that keeps it around (e.g. making it a property of the view controller that is showing the video).

You describe your use of `weakSelf` to prevent a "retain cycle" (now often called a "strong reference cycle"). Yes, the `weakSelf` pattern is used to prevent strong reference cycles. Technically, it's not entirely clear that you necessarily had a strong reference cycle at all. It depends upon the details of the `loadValuesAsynchronousForKey...` implementation (e.g. is this block loaded into some class property, thus creating strong reference cycle from the class, to a block class property references of `self`, which in turn maintains a strong reference back to `self`).

But that's all a bit academic: The `weakSelf` pattern is prudent nonetheless, because it accurately reflects the appropriate object graph (the block has no business "owning" and/or maintaining a strong reference to the video player). Coincidentally, though, when you use `weakSelf`, it also eliminates the potential risk of strong reference cycle.

The real issue is that you presumably want to keep the video player in scope not just while the assets are loaded, but while the video plays, too, so you'd want to change the scope of the video player regardless (presumably to match the view controller that is presenting the video player.

Answer (score 3):

That's the idea of weak variables: Weak variables do *not* hold a reference count, so if a weak variable is the only thing left that holds on to an object, the object will be deallocated and the weak variable will be nil. That's 100% the way how weak variables are supposed to work and supposed to be used.

If you had used a strong reference, then your block would be the only bit of code still holding on to self, and all the work that you do with self would be pointless because nobody else will ever take notice of it. Since you are using a weak variable, you can avoid this by checking whether the variable is nil.

In a multithreaded environment, the last strong reference could go away at any time and your weak reference might become nil at any time. You avoid this by copying the weak variable into a strong one as the very first thing in your block, so you know the weak variable might have disappeared before you entered the block, but it won't disappear while your block is executing.

Answer (score 1):

The reason to have a weak reference for blocks is to not retain the class with the block.
Weak references get nil when the instance does not exist anymore, so you need to take care of handling the weak reference accordingly (which you do in your code).
If that is not what you want to achieve, you need to make sure your instance is not deallocated, but that is not related to your block ...